# Overriding my company's proprietary pypi repository for a specific package (kaggle)

Tags: python, pypi, kaggle

I want to install the [kaggle package](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api) on my employer's laptop, but it does not exist in the proprietary pypi mirror they have configured.

How do I bypass their pypi repo for the default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install directly using a url:

```
pip install kaggle -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```